# What time do you go [in for/at]?

Tags: prepositions, questions, phrasal-verbs

What is the correct way of saying the sentence below?

> “What time do you go in for?” OR “What time do you go in at?”

In context I mean like going into work.

I asked my husband what time he had to be in for (work) and he told me that what I said made no sense but I’ve been using that phrase my whole life. I just want to know what’s the correct way of saying it.

Answer (score 1):

> What time do you go in at?

This is right. The answer goes with "at": "I go in *at 9am*".

> What time do you go in for?

Incorrect.  If you want to use "for", then it should include the full phrase: "What time do you have to be there *for that appointment*?" "At what time must you leave *for work*?"

If a plain "for" ends the sentence, then the question/answer should match "for".

Example:

"What for?" means something similar to "why?"

"What would you go there for?"  "To get the car fixed, of course. *For* the car repair."

Answer (score 0):

Both are perfectly good (in my British English), but have a slightly different meaning.

> What time do you go in at? or What time do you go in?

suggests that there is an exact time that you aim to be in.

> What time do you go in for?

suggests that there is a time by which you will normally be in.

The distinction is more natural in the answer:

> I go into work at 9.

means that I generally get there pretty exactly at 9.

> I got into work for 9.

means I aim to be there before 9, but it's a bit more vague.

Comment: You are saying "I got into work for 9 o'clock" and _not_ necessarily as an abbreviation of "I got into work for the 9 o'clock shift"?    imho, "for" here  sounds unusual.   Could you pick out which "for" definition it matches from the list of definitions at dictionary.com or wiktionary.org?

Comment: No, I can't find it in Wiktionary, or Dictionary.com, or the OED. But I can find a few examples in the GloWbE and iWeb corpora - mostly  British: " was at the RCL offices for noon"; "Be here for noon"; "Leave Tuesday morning, be back for noon "; "I hope to be there be for noon on Friday"; "bring him to the venue for seven thirty in the evening"